# isMemberOfClass returns NO while isEqualToString:NSStringFromClass returns YES

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have CustomView inherit NSView.
Here is part of the code:

```
NSView* nsView = [(NSView*)[window contentView] hitTest:rctWindow.origin];

if([nsView isMemberOfClass:[CustomView class]] == NO)
    std::cout << "isMemberOfClass failed.";

if ([NSStringFromClass([nsView class]) isEqualToString:NSStringFromClass([CustomView class])] == NO)
    std::cout << "isEqualToString:NSStringFromClass failed.";
```

The first string is constantly printed, meaning isMemberOfClass failing.
The second string is never printed meaning isEqualToString:NSStringFromClass succeeds.

The nsView is actually pointing to CustomView class, so isEqualToString:NSStringFromClass is working correctly, while isMemberOfClass is not.

What am I missing?

Comment: I just tested this myself, and am not seeing the same behavior.  But could you try declaring `nsView` as `CustomView *nsView` and see what happens there?

Comment: Are you sure that your CustomView (or some custom superclass) doesn't override `-isMemberOfClass:`?

Comment: A O - Tried it. Same thing. Taylor - Absolutely sure.